# Array to string conversion in stored procedure laravel

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures

I want insert my form to SQL Server from laravel using a stored procedure. But I get an error

> Array to string conversion

Please help.

This is my controller

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->qty_req); $i++) {
    $answers[] = [
        'qty_req' => $request->qty_req[$i],
        'qty_alc' => $request->qty_req[$i],
        'komponen' => $request->komponen[$i],
        'qty_bo'=>$request->qty_bo[$i],
        'kode_proyek'=>$request->kode_proyek,
        'nama_proyek'=>$request->nama_proyek,
        'proyek_sap'=>$request->proyek_sap,
        'kode_panel'=>$request->kode_panel,
        'nama_panel'=>$request->nama_panel,
        'foreman'=>$request->foreman
    ];
    }
    DB::insert('EXEC insertBPK ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?',$answers);
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertBPK
    @kode_proyek nvarchar(MAX),
    @nama_proyek nvarchar(MAX),
    @kode_panel nvarchar(MAX),
    @nama_panel nvarchar(MAX),
    @proyek_sap nvarchar(MAX),
    @foreman nvarchar(MAX),
    @komponen nvarchar(MAX),
    @qty_req nvarchar(MAX),
    @qty_alc nvarchar(MAX),
    @qty_bo nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO bpk (kode_proyek, nama_proyek, kode_panel, nama_panel, proyek_sap, foreman, komponen, qty_req, qty_alc, qty_bo)
    VALUES (@kode_proyek, @nama_proyek, @kode_panel, @nama_panel, @proyek_sap, @foreman, @komponen, @qty_req, @qty_alc, @qty_bo);
END
GO
```

This is my blade

```
<td class="text-center" style="width: 100px;">
    <input type="number" name="qty_req[]" class="form-control" max="{{$open_qty}}" min="0">
    <input type="text" name="komponen[]" value="{{$lk->komponen}}" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="qty_bo[]" value="{{$lk->qty_bo}}" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="kode_proyek" value="{{$kode_proyek}}" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="proyek_sap" value="{{$proyek_sap}}" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="nama_proyek" value="{{$nama_proyek}}" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="kode_panel" value="{{$kode_panel}}" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="nama_panel" value="{{$nama_panel}}" hidden>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: in my controller, if i submit form, i get error massage ''Array to string conversion bla...bla.."

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the documentation first [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaQKB.png), `DB::insert()` requires raw SQL, maybe you can change it into insert SQL. Change it into `DB::insert('INSERT INTO bpk VALUES(...)',$answers)`

Also `DB::insert` requires 2 parameters, first one is string and the second is an array, but on the second parameter you passed an 2 dimensional array, maybe you can change `$answers[]` into `$answer` and the array supposed to be a normal array (as far as I know) and you passed an associative array, maybe you could try changing `$answer` that you passed in the `DB::insert('...',$answers);` into `DB::insert('...',array_values($answers));`

Good luck :)